# Batch - move file by multi file name patterns/conditions

Tags: batch-file

I know I can use

```
move %~dp0\Microsoft*.dll %~dp0\ObjectFolder
move %~dp0\Microsoft*.pdb %~dp0\ObjectFolder
```

to move `dll` and `pdb` file to another folder.

I want to ask can the 2 conditions be merged in one line? such as something like `[pdb,dll]`:

```
move %~dp0\Microsoft*.[pdb,dll] %~dp0\ObjectFolder
```

Comment: Please note that `%~dp0` is replaced by Window command interpreter during preprocessing by path of batch file always ending with a backslash. Therefore don't add an additional backslash after each `%~dp0` in code of batch file.

Comment: @Mofi, I agree, the additional `\ `is not necessary; but it does not harm either, because `D:\Test\data` points to the same location as `D:\Test\\data` anyway...

Comment: @aschipfl It is right that Windows fixes mis-formed paths automatically before accessing file system, I think since Windows Nt4 using internally the kernel function [GetFullPathName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963.aspx). But it is better to avoid mis-formed paths, especially when that is so easy like here. I prefer well-formed paths in batch files in case of outputting them or passing them to applications which are not so path syntax tolerant like Windows kernel is nowadays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to put multiple search masks into a single command.

The only way I can think of to put all in a single line is to use a [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html):

```cmd
for %%I in ("%~dp0Microsoft*.dll" "%~dp0Microsoft*.pdb") do move "%%~I" "%~dp0ObjectFolder"
```

---

As an alternative the [`robocopy` command](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) could be used, which accepts multiple file names or patterns:

```cmd
robocopy "%~dp0." "%~dp0ObjectFolder" "Microsoft*.dll" "Microsoft*.pdb" /MOV
```

---

#### Note

The help text of the [`move` command](http://ss64.com/nt/move.html) seems to be wrong, it does actually **not** accept a comma-separated list of source files (when the destination is a directory):

> ```cmd
> To move one or more files:
> MOVE [/Y | /-Y] [drive:][path]filename1[,...] destination
> ```